# What is a natural exact sequence?

Tags: category-theory, terminology, sheaf-theory

I know what an exact sequence is, but I have searched for the definition of a *natural* exact sequence, and could not find it.

Does "natural" perhaps mean some sort of preservation of structure?

I have seen the term "natural exact sequence" in an assignment problem on sheaf theory, which is as follows:

> Let $X$ be a topological space, $Z\subset X$ a closed subset, and $U=X\setminus Z$. Let $i:Z\hookrightarrow X$ and $j:U\hookrightarrow X$ be the corresponding inclusions. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf (in abelian groups) on $X$. Show that we have a natural exact sequence of sheaves on $X$:
>   $$
> 0\rightarrow j_{!}\left(\mathcal{F}_{U}\right)\rightarrow\mathcal{F}\rightarrow i_{*}\left(\mathcal{F}_{Z}\right)\rightarrow0
> $$
>   where $j_{!}\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf defined as $V\mapsto\mathcal{F}\left(V\right)$ if $V\subset U$ and $V\mapsto0$ otherwise.

Also, doing a search on Google, I've seen it in a number of research articles and similar material.

Comment: Why do you expect there is a definition of "natural exact sequence"?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I've seen it in an assignment problem on sheaf theory.

Comment: Well, you could give that context then. What did the assignment say, &c-

Comment: Natural here means natural in the usual sense of category theory (e.g. natural transformation), that is: functorial.  For example, given a construction associating to any space $X$ an exact sequence $E(X)$, naturality would mean that given a morphism $X \to Y$, one gets an induced morphism $E(X) \to E(Y)$ of exact sequences (in such a way that $E$ defines a functor).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that the maps occuring in the sequence are actually components of natural transformations (between certain functors $\mathsf{Sh}(X) \to \mathsf{Sh}(X)$). Explicitly, it means that for a homomorphism of sheaves $F \to G$ the diagram
$$\begin{array}{c} 0 & \to & j_! F_U & \to & F & \to & i_* F_Z & \to & 0 \\ & & \downarrow && \downarrow && \downarrow & \\ 0 & \to & j_! G_U & \to & G & \to & i_* G_Z & \to & 0\end{array}$$
commutes. Typically one doesn't really verify this because it is "obvious" (depending on mathematical maturity).

Comment: Since English is not my native language, I just wanted to check if the word "mathematical maturity" is correct at all, and even found this Wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_maturity

Comment: Indeed, I found some examples of natural transformations in the lecture notes, and in all of them, this property is mentioned as obvious.