# Naturality as functoriality on arrow category

Tags: category-theory

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1071797/exactness-and-naturality) it is said that a natural transformation $\varphi:F\Rightarrow G$ is the same as a function $\varphi_0:\mathrm{Ob}\mathcal A\rightarrow \mathrm{Mor}\mathcal B$ satisfying ${\rm dom}\circ\varphi=F,{\rm cod}\circ\varphi=G$. That naturality implies this functoriality is clear, but I'm having trouble with the converse. I don't see how to show $Gf\circ \varphi_A=\varphi_B\circ Ff$.

Answer (score 2):

You should read again: it says that it is a **functor** $\varphi\colon \mathcal A \to \mathcal B^{\to}$ where $\mathcal B^\to$ is the arrow category of $\mathcal B$. The function $\operatorname{Ob}\mathcal A \to \operatorname{Mor}{\mathcal B}$ you are talking about is only the object-mapping part of the functor.

The naturality condition is actually taken into account by the action on the arrows of $\mathcal A$: more precisely, an arrow $f\colon a \to b$ of $\mathcal A$ should be transported to an arrow of $\mathcal B^\to$ (i.e. a commutative square of $\mathcal B$) whose domain is $F(f)$ and codomain is $G(f)$.